# How to get min max day in a week every month?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to make something a value that outputs a date of first day in the week and last one in the week respectively. For example:
In february a week one from monday to sunday there will be a date 1 - 7, and week two from monday to sunday there will be date 8 - 14, and so on until the last day of month.
Here for example is the result that I want as list

[image]

Here is my code that I tried to produce but it's giving wrong output:

```
                ListWeek week;
                List<ListWeek> listWeek =new  List<ListWeek>();

                var mins = listCrews[0].days; 
                var maxs = 0;

                for (int rows = 0; rows < listCrews.Count; rows++)
                {
                    week = new ListWeek();
                    var weeknumbers = listCrews[rows].weeks;
                    var dayNumbers = listCrews[rows].days;
                    
                    week.weeknumber = weeknumbers;
                    if(rows == 0)
                    {   
                        week.days_min =  dayNumbers;
                        week.days_max = dayNumbers;
                    }else{
                        if(dayNumbers < mins)
                        {
                            mins = dayNumbers;
                            week.days_min = mins;
                            week.days_max = maxs;
                        }else if(dayNumbers > maxs)
                        {
                            maxs = dayNumbers;
                            week.days_min = mins;
                            week.days_max = maxs;
                        }
                        else{
                            week.days_min = dayNumbers;
                            week.days_max = dayNumbers;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    week.month = listCrews[rows].month_name;
                    week.year = listCrews[rows].year;

                    if(!listWeek.Contains(week))
                    {
                        listWeek.Add(week);
                    }
                }

               // i tried to check it
               foreach (var weekly in listWeek)
               {
                    Console.WriteLine("here "  + weekly.weeknumber + " " + weekly.days_min+ " " + + weekly.days_max);
               }
```

and here is the example json (I have just included one because it's too long)

```
 [
   {
    "days": 1,
    "days_name": "Monday",
    "weeks": 1,
    "month": 2,
    "month_name": "February",
    "year": 2021,
   },
   {
    "days": 2,
    "days_name": "Thursday",
     ....
   }
 ]
```

every list crews has a json from days, listcrews 0 days is 1 and listcrews 1 days is 2 and so on, according to february days because it's started from monday

and through my code i only produce this

[image]

How can i complete this??

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what the requirements are. You need to clarify what you mean by… _”a value that outputs a date of first day in the week and last one in the week respectively.”_ … ? … I am not understanding this… the FIRST day of any month could be ANY day of the week, so I am not sure what you mean by… _”date of first day in the week and last one in the week respectively”_ … this appears to assume that the first day of all months is “always” the same day of the week?

Comment: In your example… _”In february a week one from monday to sunday there will be a date 1 – 7”_ … this may well be true for some years; however, it is not necessarily true for other years. If the year is irrelevant, then this appears to have nothing to do with a date or which day of the week the date falls on. From the title… what is the “min” day in a week every month? … One (1). Max would be the last day of that month? Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Lastly, if you ARE needing to figure out something like, what day of the week is the first day of February 2020… then I highly encourage you to use `DateTime` objects instead of manually trying to figure this out. [DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) … [System.DateTime Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/system-datetime-methods)

Comment: if you look at the callendar , you can see the day of the first week are for that month, because the first day will be on sunday until saturday that kind of things, you can look at the may, you can see the first week will only day 1, second week are 2 until 8, that's what i mean, you can make 2 as the min, and max as the 8, for week 2, and the next one  is week 3, it will be min 9 and max is 15 that's the answer i want to look it for

Comment: Still not 100% clear. Assuming the weeks start on “Sunday” and, using this month “May” 2021… the FIRST day of May 2021 is a Saturday. So that first week is 1, the second week is 2-8 etc. If this is the case, then as I said… all you need to know is “WHICH” day of the week the FIRST day of that month/year falls on. It will obviously be one of the days Sunday – Saturday. Whichever day of the week the first day is will dictate what the other values will be. If the first day is on Friday, then week 1 is 1,2 and week 2 is 3-9 etc…

Comment: you can look at my explanations above at my first picture, my first day are monday, and the last day are sunday

Comment: It is irrelevant “which” day of the week you start your weeks off at. All you need to know is “which day of the week” the FIRST day of the given month/year is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, this is much easier if you use `DateTime` objects. Anytime you have to deal with dates or times… Use a `DateTime` object. I posted a couple of links in my comment.

The code below simply loops through each day of the given month/year. If the “day of the week” for that date is either a `StartingDayOfWeek` or `EndingDayOfWeek` then print that day. Some additional code for checking end and boundary cases.

***Edit...***

An additional check is needed if the last day of the month falls on the `StartingDayOfWeek`. In which case the last day would be both the min and max.

```
private const DayOfWeek StartingDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday;
private const DayOfWeek EndingDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;

static void Main(string[] args) {
  DisplayWeekDatesFromGivenMonthYear(2, 2021);
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void DisplayWeekDatesFromGivenMonthYear(int month, int year) {
  DateTime tempDT = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
  Console.WriteLine("Date " + tempDT.ToShortDateString() + "----");
  int curWeek = 1;
  while (tempDT.Month == month) {
    // is this day the 1st or any date that is the starting day of the week
    if (tempDT.Date.Day == 1 || tempDT.DayOfWeek == StartingDayOfWeek) {
      Console.WriteLine("Week " + curWeek + "----");
      Console.Write("  min: " + tempDT.Day);
      if (tempDT.DayOfWeek == EndingDayOfWeek ||
          tempDT.Date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) {
        Console.WriteLine("  max: " + tempDT.Day);
        curWeek++;
      }
    }
    else {
      // is this day at the end of the week
      if (tempDT.DayOfWeek == EndingDayOfWeek) {
        Console.WriteLine("  max: " + tempDT.Day);
        curWeek++;
      }
      else {
        // check for last day in month
        if (tempDT.Date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)) {
          Console.WriteLine("  max: " + tempDT.Day);
        }
      }
    }
    tempDT = tempDT.AddDays(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it but, i hope there is someone who can make my code shorter

here is my code

```
               var mins = listCrews[0].days;
                var maxs = 0;

                for (int rows = 0; rows < listCrews.Count; rows++)
                {
                    week = new ListWeek();
                    var weeknumbers = listCrews[rows].weeks;
                    var dayNumbers = listCrews[rows].days;

                    week.weeknumber = weeknumbers;
                    if (rows == 0)
                    {
                        week.days_min = dayNumbers;
                        week.days_max = dayNumbers;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (weeknumbers != listCrews[rows - 1].weeks)
                        {
                            mins = maxs + 1;
                            if (dayNumbers < mins)
                            {
                                mins = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_min = mins;
                                week.days_max = maxs;
                            }
                            else if (dayNumbers > maxs)
                            {
                                maxs = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_min = mins;
                                week.days_max = maxs;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                week.days_min = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_max = dayNumbers;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (dayNumbers < mins)
                            {
                                mins = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_min = mins;
                                week.days_max = maxs;
                            }
                            else if (dayNumbers > maxs)
                            {
                                maxs = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_min = mins;
                                week.days_max = maxs;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                week.days_min = dayNumbers;
                                week.days_max = dayNumbers;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    week.month = listCrews[rows].month_name;
                    week.year = listCrews[rows].year;

                    if (!listWeek.Contains(week))
                    {
                        listWeek.Add(week);
                    }
                }
                NewListWeek:

                for (int rows = 0; rows < listWeek.Count; rows++)
                {
                    if(rows != 0)
                    {
                        if(listWeek[rows -1].weeknumber == listWeek[rows].weeknumber && listWeek[rows -1].days_max < listWeek[rows].days_max)
                        {
                            listWeek.Remove(listWeek[rows-1]);
                            goto NewListWeek;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var weekly in listWeek)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("here " + weekly.weeknumber + " " + weekly.days_min + " " + +weekly.days_max + " " + weekly.month + " " + weekly.year);
                }
```

and here is the result

[image]